# what to do with the gap on my css drop down menu?

Tags: php, html, css

I badly need help with my css coding. newbie here.

```
#accountTitle
padding: 0;
display: block;
margin-top: 90px;
margin-bottom: -120px;
margin-left: 50px;
font-size: 36px;


a:active 
background-color: #a6d8a8;




table 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 50px;
overflow-x:auto;


 td 
  text-align:left;

   th, td

padding: 15px;



th 
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;



tr:hover 
background-color: #a6d8a8;
cursor: pointer;




#container 
margin-top: 135px;
position: relative;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
border-radius: 10px;
width: 100%;




.wrap
margin-right: 10px;
text-align: center;



.dropbtn

background-color: #333;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;



.dropdown 
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 5px;



   .dropdown-content 

    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 2;


     .dropdown-content a 
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;


        .dropdown-content a:hover 
         background-color: #f1f1f1

         .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content
          display: block;



          .dropdown:hover .dropbtn 
           background-color: #434343;



<label id="accountTitle">Audit Log</label>
<div id="container">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn" id="homebtn">Home</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Main Page</a>
<a href="#">Accounts</a>
<a href="#">Audit Log</a>
<a href="#">Logout</a>
</div>
</div>
```

**The problem** here is that, whenever I scroll down this happens

[image]

please i really need to finish this.

Comment: could you share in any fiddle with html to better understand...!@Marky

Comment: The code you posted is A) not even legal CSS and B) not complete code, it doesn't provide us with what you posted in the picture. From the code you posted, everything looks fine.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cloudsky21/axz7dodo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take the `overflow` out of `#container` and change the `position` on `.dropdown-content` to `absolute`

```
#container {
    ...
    padding: 0;
    /* overflow: hidden; DELETE THIS */
    background-color: #333;
    ...
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position:  absolute;
    ...
}
```

Comment: it works!!!! thank you!!! i've been killing myself for almost a day now.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the padding of `.dropdown-content a`  should be like this

```
   .dropdown-content a 
{
      color: black;
      padding: 0px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the problem very well but if the problem is that dropdown is not appearing at all then you have to change your `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content` like this.

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
      display: block;
      z-index: 1;
 }
```

z-index change html rendering priority according to the number it has, the bigger number is the bigger the priority is.

Comment: i have a table filled with data, lets say 50 rows of data and i need to scroll down the page but whenever i hover back my menu, there's a gap between the drop content and the HOME text link. Sorry about my grammar, I'm really not that good in English.

Comment: Now I get it, then just do as amallard says